# Rewrite Rule htacces searches for css in wrong folder

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

When I add my HTaccess Rewrite Rules, my paths for `scr` attributes with intern use, are being shifted. For the first rule all CSS works fine but when it adds a second variable in the link my css files and script files are suddenly called out of a wrong folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jellyfish_rework/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

In the first rule, everything works perfect. for example when my link is with one variable (the p variable for page) it works as it should be. The link in this case ends up being `http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/blog`. and the css and scripts are being called normally

`<link href="css/jellyfish.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` would be then the link to my css style sheet.

However, when my t (stands for title) variable is filled in, when for example I am trying to find a specific post in my blog, my whole links change. Chrome Console will output on `http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website` the following:

```
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/css/font-awesome.min.css  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:23
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/css/jellyfish.css  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:24
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/css/bootstrap.min.css  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:22
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/css/animate.css  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:25
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/js/custom/knob.js  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:168
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:166
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/js/custom/wow.min.js  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:167
GET http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/artikel/js/custom/jellyfish.js  Lancering-van-onze-nieuwe-website:169
```

Why is it adding the `/article/` to the relative path of my scripts and css? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into this problem due to your use of relative URLs in css/js/images. You can fix it one of the ways:

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. Otherwise try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Jep, as you posted this, i found the answer myself as well. i added the `<BASE href="http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/">` in the header tag and it works fine now. Thanks for the help!